Nuxt build issue: Lexical.node.mjs not found, only Lexical.prod.mjs present
I'm using Nuxt and Lexical.js and I'm trying to build the project with the nuxt build command. After this, my dependencies are placed in the .output/server/node_modules folder in a compiled form.
However, when running the built project, Nuxt requests the Lexical.node.mjs file, while only Lexical.prod.mjs is present in the folder.
The package.json inside .output/node_module/Lexical looks like this:
{
  "name": "lexical",
  "description": "Lexical is an extensible text editor framework that provides excellent reliability, accessible and performance.",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "lexical",
    "editor",
    "contenteditable",
    "rich-text"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "version": "0.16.0",
  "main": "Lexical.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/facebook/lexical",
    "directory": "packages/lexical"
  },
  "module": "Lexical.mjs",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": {
        "types": "./index.d.ts",
        "development": "./Lexical.dev.mjs",
        "production": "./Lexical.prod.mjs",
        "node": "./Lexical.node.mjs",
        "default": "./Lexical.prod.mjs"
      },
      "require": {
        "types": "./index.d.ts",
        "development": "./Lexical.dev.js",
        "production": "./Lexical.prod.js",
        "default": "./Lexical.prod.js"
      }
    }
  }
}

Here we can see that there's an export for Lexical.node.mjs, however, it's not created during the build process. What's happening here and how can I fix this?
